# Creating Stored Procedure in versioned SDE_SQLServer geodatabase using DDL?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, versioning

I've almost used SQL server_SDE geodatabases for 3 years in GIS projects and I don't know how can I create a stored procedure in geodatabase.I use ESRI case tool to create a geodatabase in ArcCatalog(using xml file as described in ESRI documentations),so I never created a geodatabase with DDL scripts,But i would like to know (and do) creating a geodatabase using DDL commands in SQL Server(while using SDE and versioning) and adding stored procedure to this geodatabase.As I know,sde creates some metadata tables and breaks data of versioned tables into some other tables(like a_xx and f_xx,for example a89,f89) so that  some records of table is saved in these helping tables,so that I don't know how can I find the name of these helping tables and basically do i have to work with them in stored procedure or not.

Is there any document or guide line to show how can create a geodatabase using DDL command in an environment like SQL server management studio?and how can create stored procedures in geodatabase and how can call it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL Server geodatabases are like any other SQL Server database.  Writing and accessing stored procedures for data in the geodatabases will not be any different.

Here is a presentation from ESRI on how to use SQL in a geodatabase:

http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/devsummit09/papers/sql_and_gdb.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much Seth,I found this file useful,but not enough details included as it's a presentation.do you think it's possible to work with a geoDB using an object model other than ArcObject,say ODBC or OLEDB,just like a a non_GeoDB database in ESRI's application?

Comment: @Reza - Entity Framework 4 offers some support to modeling geodatabases, even though it currently requires a hack to represent spatial types.  You may want to give that a try.